# BufferedWriter writing 0 as \00 into text file

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter

I have something like

```
int userChoice;
System.out.println("Enter your choice");
userChoice = userInput.nextInt(); //Scanner stuffs written already
```

Let's say the user chooses 0.

When I try to use BufferedWriter and write into a text file.

I get \00 being written to the file instead of 0.

Below are my codes..

```
try {

    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("salt.txt", true)));
    output.write(userChoice);
    output.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So how do I make it that it writes '0' to the file rather than '\00'

Comment: OutputStreamWriter has a write(int) method, but will interpret the value as a character code.  If you want to make it printable, first convert your int value to a string or similar printable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably prefer to use a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), but you should be able to do something like this -

```
// output.write(userChoice);
output.write(String.valueOf(userChoice));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use write(int c), it interprets the integer as a character (like an ASCII value). Try converting userChoice into a String when writing it.

```
output.write(Integer.toString(userChoice));
output.write("" + userChoice);
```